# Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn returns password error but doesn't show Facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn() to authenticate a user with Facebook login. The code seems to run but it returns an error "missing user password". However the Facbook sign in page isn't shown for the user to enter their details. It goes straight to the error message.

My ionic project app.js has the following relevant code in the $ionicPlatform.ready() function (IDs are fake for the purposes of this posting):

```js
Parse.initialize("AAT7Gx1DHZrIgEuTpaqnwVZmOH9DBSEbyV5AUo2Q", "AAj7pus7oZwODd61ITsupfg04dRuV0nPfMxrPcC8");
    if(!(ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid())){
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
          appId      : '991974558512540',
          version    : 'v2.3',
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };
      (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
```

This code is pretty much cut and pasted from the Facebook site. When this code is run ionic.Platform.isIOS() it true as I am running on an iPhone.

My code for using Parse to do Facebook authentication is:

```js
   Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(['publish_stream', 'email'], {
      success: function(user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (!user.existed()) {
          alert("You have signed up and logged in through Facebook! : "+JSON.stringify(user));
        } else {
          alert("You are logged in through Facebook! : "+JSON.stringify(user));
        }
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    });
```

Comment: is there a reason you are not using the Facebook Plugin? I find it to work better then dealing with the Javascript Library and you have access to the native UI

Comment: Which Facebook plugin do you use?

Comment: the one that comes with ngCordova documentation